# Difference between tf.nn_conv2d and tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

What is the difference between `tf.nn_conv2d` and `tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d` in Tensorflow?

Comment: Have you seen documentation for both functions? Have you noticed that they calculate different things? If so, then the answer to your question is obvious: one calculates this, another something different.

Comment: No, I have not. They stated the same thing.

Comment: Except the other one you can explicitly define the kernel size.

Comment: What I meant was, I have seen the documentation, but didn't exactly get the distinction between the two.

Comment: I don't know about these "advices" that simply tell you to go RTFM.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I am no expert on this, but as far as I understand the difference is this:

Lets say you have an input colour image with length 100, width 100. So the dimensions are 100x100x3. For both examples we use the same filter of width and height 5. Lets say we want the next layer to have a depth of 8.

In tf.nn.conv2d you define the kernel shape as [width, height, in_channels, out_channels]. In our case this means the kernel has shape [5,5,3,out_channels].
The weight-kernel that is strided over the image has a shape of 5x5x3, and it is strided over the whole image 8 times to produce 8 different feature maps.

In tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d you define the kernel shape as [width, height, in_channels, channel_multiplier]. Now the output is produced differently. Separate filters of 5x5x1 are strided over each dimension of the input image, one filter per dimension, each producing one feature map per dimension. So here, a kernel size [5,5,3,1] would produce an output with depth 3. The channel_multiplier tells you how many different filters you want to apply **per dimension**. So the original desired output of depth 8 is not possible with 3 input dimensions. Only multiples of 3 are possible.

Answer (score 11):

Let's see the sample code in [TensorFlow API(r1.7)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/)

For `depthwise_conv2d`,

```
output[b, i, j, k * channel_multiplier + q] =
    sum_{di, dj} input[b, strides[1] * i + rate[0] * di,
                          strides[2] * j + rate[1] * dj, k] *
                 filter[di, dj, k, q]
```

filter is `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, channel_multiplier]`

For `conv2d`,

```
output[b, i, j, k] =
    sum_{di, dj, q} input[b, strides[1] * i + di,
                             strides[2] * j + dj, q] *
                    filter[di, dj, q, k]
```

filter is `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]`

Focusing on `k` and `q`, we can see the difference shown above.

The default format is `NHWC`, where `b` is batch size, `(i, j)` is a coordinate in feature map.

(Note that `k` and `q` refer to different things in this two functions.)

1. For `depthwise_conv2d`, `k` refers to an input channel and `q`, `0 <= q < channel_multiplier`, refers to an output channel. Each input channel `k` is expanded to `k*channel_multiplier` with different filters `[filter_height, filter_width, channel_multiplier]`. It does not conduct cross-channel operation, in some literature, it is referred as `channel-wise spatial convolution`. Above process can be concluded as applying kernels of each filter separately to each channel and concatenating the outputs.
2. For `conv2d`, `k` refers to an output channel and `q` refers to an input channel. It sums up among all input channels, meaning that each output channel `k` is associated with all `q` input channels by a `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels]` filter.

For example,

```
input_size: (_, 14, 14, 32)
filter of conv2d: (3, 3, 32, 64)
params of conv2d filter: 3x3x32x64
filter of depthwise_conv2d: (3, 3, 32, 64)
params of depthwise_conv2d filter: 3x3x32x64
```

suppose stride = 1 with padding, then

```
output of conv2d: (_, 14, 14, 64)
output of depthwise_conv2d: (_, 14, 14, 32*64)
```

Some more insights:

- Standard convolution operation can be split into 2 steps: depthwise convolution and reduction (sum).
- Depthwise Convolution is equivalent to setting the number of group to input channel in Group Convolution.
- Usually, `depthwise_conv2d` is followed by `pointwise_conv2d`(a 1x1 convolution for reduction purpose), making a `separable_conv2d`. Check [Xception](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02357.pdf), [MobileNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04861.pdf) for more details.

Comment: are you sure that in `depthwise_conv2d` the filter is the same for all the same channel copies? from the definition, I have that the filter matrix has the dimension k (channel) and the dimensione q (moltiplier) so it seems that there is a different matrix (i.e. a different filter) for every copy of the channel...

Comment: yes, you're right. Each input channel associates with different filters. I'll revise the answer. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Link is broken. Here is another one https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/depthwise_conv2d

Answer (score 1):

The tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d means using **N** different filters for each input channel. The output will have **N * channel_multiplier** different output channels. Run the code and you will find out.

```html
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
# input image with 10x10 shape for 3 channels
# filter with 10x10 shape for each input channel

N_in_channel = 3
N_out_channel_mul = 8
x = tf.random_normal([1, 10, 10, N_in_channel])
f = tf.random_normal([10, 10, N_in_channel, N_out_channel_mul])
y = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(x, f, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID", data_format="NHWC")

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

x_data, f_data, y_conv = sess.run([x, f, y])

y_s = np.squeeze(y_conv)
for i in range(N_in_channel):
    for j in range(N_out_channel_mul):
        print("np: %f, tf:%f" % (np.sum(x_data[0, :, :, i] * f_data[:, :, i, j]), y_s[i * N_out_channel_mul + j]))
```